# WScript/CScript crashes when logging on using Outlook Redemption

Tags: vbscript, outlook-redemption, outlook-2013, wsh

**Background/Issue/Question**

I just installed Outlook 2013 (64-bit) on my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine and I'm using the developer version of Outlook Redemption to test it out with Outlook 2013 after successfully using it for development with Outlook 2010. I downloaded the newest Redemption files and used the installer to install and register the DLLs.

Now, when I try to run a VBScript against Redemption using `WScript.exe` or `CScript.exe`, WScript/CScript crash.

Does anyone know why WScript/CScript would be crashing (see details below)?

**Code**

Here's my code:

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
WScript.Echo "Session created."
WScript.Echo Session.Version
Session.Logon("Outlook")
WScript.Echo "Logged on with default profile."
Session.Logoff
```

**Error**

The code fails when it gets to `Session.Logon("Outlook")`. Here's the error message I'm receiving and some additional details:

```
Microsoft Windows Based Script Host has stopped working

Problem details
-------------------
Problem Event Name:     APPCRASH
Application Name:       WScript.exe
Application Version:    5.8.7601.18283
Application Timestamp:  5258a6e6
Fault Module Name:      mso.dll
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 567a40e6
Exception Code:         c0000005
Exception Offset:       000000000135991f
OS Version:             6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
```

**Troubleshooting**

I tried renaming MSO.dll and repairing Outlook, but that had no effect. I also tried re-creating the default profile (called 'Outlook'), but that also had no effect.

I also tried installing Redemption using `regsvr32.exe`.

I ensured that I was using the 64-bit version of `WScript.exe` and `CScript.exe`.

For the sake of posterity, I tested to find out if I could connect to MAPI with Redemption. Here's the code:

```
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Session = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Session.Logon("Outlook")

Set rdoSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
WScript.Echo "RDOSession created."
WScript.Echo rdoSession.Version
rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = Session.MAPIOBJECT
WScript.Echo "RDOSession MAPIOBJECT created."
rdoSession.Logoff
Session.Logoff
```

The above code works fine in both `WScript.exe` and `CScript.exe`, probably because the Outlook Object Model is being used to create the Outlook session and Redemption is just hooking in.

**Note** -- I can't use the last bit of code for what I plan on doing because the above code won't work from Windows Task Scheduler if my machine is locked or I'm logged off (it only works if I'm logged on). I should point out that the first code snippet worked fine with Outlook 2010, although I was running Outlook 2010 32-bit with Windows 7 64-bit. For Outlook 2013, I decided to move to 64-bit.

Comment: What services are in that profile? What version of Redemption are you using?

Comment: There's just an email account and some data files associated with the profile (I didn't change anything about the profile from 2010 to 2013, except I removed and re-created it). I'm using the latest developer version, 5.10.0.4312.

Comment: Send an email to address at the Redemption support page, and I will send you the debug version of the dll.